# Post Method Not giving Alerts like planned?

Tags: javascript, post

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div align="center"><legend>Add a Code</legend>
<label for="code"></label>
<input type="text" name="code" id="code" maxlength="10" />
<input type='button' 
 onclick=
             "isAlphanumeric(document.getElementById('code'),'Your Submission Contained Invalid Characters'); 
              isBadPhrase(document.getElementById('code'), 'Please Enter A Correct Friend Code!');"     
     value='Check Field' />
```

```
function isAlphanumeric(elem, helperMsg){
var alphaExp = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
    return true;
}else{
    alert(helperMsg);
    elem.focus();   
    return false;
}
```

}

```
function isBadPhrase(elem,helperMsg){
var badPhrase=/EPW|ESW|\s/;
if (elem.value.match(badPhrase)){
    alert(helperMsg);
    elem.focus();
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
    }
```

}

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning anything from your handler.  You need to return a value (true/false) from the handler, especially if you want to stop the default.  Note -- I'd also change the name of the "BadPhrase" method to "GoodPhrase" so that it matches the sense of the return value.

script:

```
function isAlphanumeric(elem, helperMsg){
    var alphaExp = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
        return true;
    } else {
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function isGoodPhrase(elem,helperMsg){
    var badPhrase=/EPW|ESW|\s/;
    if (elem.value.match(badPhrase)){
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function checkInput(id)    {
    return isAlphanumeric(document.getElementById(id),'Your Submission Contained Invalid Characters')
        && isGoodPhrase(document.getElementById(id), 'Please Enter A Correct Friend Code!');
}
```

html:

```
<input type='button' onclick="return checkInput('code');" value='Check Field' />
```

**EDIT**:

If you do the validation on form submit it will run regardless of how the form is submitted.  You can add it as a onsubmit handler in the form tag, like you did for the click handler of the button.  The button should probably be a submit button if it is supposed to trigger form submission.

Note: my preference would be to add the handlers via javascript rather than in the tag, but that's outside the scope of the question.  I'd also probably use a framework rather than raw javascript, but that's also outside the scope.

Comment: What do you mean?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: Is that correct?  It doesn't work.  I think you are missing something.  When I plug it into my editor all my codes colors are changed and I assume that means broken,.

Comment: I had an extra double-quote at the end.  I've fixed it.  Note that I changed the name of the function, too.

Comment: Did you change the name of your function (or change my snippet back)?  Sounds like maybe you have a javascript error on the page that is preventing the code from executing at all.

Comment: Try running it in Firefox/Firebug and see what the console tells you.

Comment: I added all the parts of your code, left my original functions just so i didn't lost them.

Comment: Did you try putting in some breakpoints in the script and examining the values during execution?

Comment: I just implemented this in a local file and it worked fine in Firefox.  I pasted the entire code that I used in my answer.

Comment: Okay, so I apologize, tvanfosson.  Your code does work.  I am incredibly stupid.  I am the type something and press return to input data, not actually click it.  Please accept my apology.  Now, I need to figure out how to make it so if people press 'return' instead of pressing the actual button for it to return an error.

Comment: Run the validation code on the form submit event rather than on button click.  That way it will run regardless of how the form is submitted.