# Alerts not working

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Post Method Not giving Alerts like planned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247065/post-method-not-giving-alerts-like-planned)

Javascript:

```
function isAlphanumeric(elem, helperMsg){
    var alphaExp = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
        return true;
    } else {
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function isGoodPhrase(elem,helperMsg){
    var badPhrase=/EPW|ESW|\s/;
    if (elem.value.match(badPhrase)){
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function checkInput(id)    {
    return isAlphanumeric(document.getElementById(id),'Your Submission Contained Invalid Characters')
        && isGoodPhrase(document.getElementById(id), 'Please Enter A Correct Friend Code!');
    }

    </script>
```

And HTML

```
    <form action="" method="post">
    <div align="center"><legend>Add a Code</legend>
    <label for="code"></label>
    <input type="text" name="code" id="code" maxlength="10" />
    <input type='button' onclick="return checkInput('code');" value='Check Field' />
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247065/post-method-not-giving-alerts-like-planned

Comment: Oh ... and there is also no 'question' here.

Comment: It's not a duplicate cause the guy changed my code and it still doesn't work.

I assumed people would realize that the question is why aren't the alerts working?

Comment: If it still doesn't work, then tell the person who answered the question he is wrong and wait for someone to come around who can actually fix it.

Comment: I wrote the code **and** tested it.  The problem must be elsewhere on the page, or perhaps with the browser.

Comment: I rolled this back so it could be closed properly as a duplicate.

Comment: Okay, so I apologize, tvanfosson.  Your code does work.  I am incredibly stupid.  I am the type something and press return to input data, not actually click it.  Please accept my apology.  Now, I need to figure out how to make it so if people press 'return' instead of pressing the actual button for it to return an error.

Answer (score 0):

alerts are working normally, i tested them.

Seams that the problem that you are testing with the right values that does not match the regex to see the alerts

Comment: to confirm above, just put alerts before the return true...